# Login screen displays in the wrong place?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, error, login

Screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Up2HPnq.jpg]

When I wake up my computer, the login screen is placed up and to the left of where it should be. Fortunately, the login screen otherwise functions normally, and everything is placed correctly after I login.

This problem started happening some time after I upgraded to Yosemite.

- Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite
- 13" mid-2013 MacBook Air, Intel Haswell Core i7

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting to upgrade to 10.10.1 seems to have fixed the problem for now.